# Adding colorbar to scatterplot after loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to add a continuous colorbar to a seaborn scatterplot (similar to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735147/how-to-color-matplotlib-scatterplot-using-a-continuous-value-seaborn-color) and in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637989/add-a-vertical-label-to-matplotlib-colormap-legend)). For my purposes, I am building the scatterplot with a loop, and then trying to add the continuous colorbar, but I dont know what object to include as argument of `fig.colorbar()`. How would you do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(42)

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 100), index=['S1','S2']).T
tars=np.random.choice([0,0.3,0.5,0.8,1], 100)
df=pd.concat([df,pd.Series(tars, name='group')],1)
colors = matplotlib.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0,1,len(pd.unique(tars))))

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
targets=pd.unique(tars)
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    ...
    g=ax.scatter(
        df.loc[df.group==target, 'S1'], 
        df.loc[df.group==target, 'S2'],
        color = [color]
    )
fig.colorbar(g)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I add `ax.legend(targets)` instead of `fig.colorbar(g)`, the legend displays correctly but is categorical.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 100), index=['S1','S2']).T
tars=np.random.choice([0,0.3,0.5,0.8,1], 100)
df=pd.concat([df,pd.Series(tars, name='group')],1)

cmap=matplotlib.cm.gnuplot2
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,len(pd.unique(tars))))

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
targets=pd.unique(tars)
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    ...
    g=ax.scatter(
        df.loc[df.group==target, 'S1'], 
        df.loc[df.group==target, 'S2'],
        color = [color]
    )
ax.legend(targets)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are the points in your example how they are supposed to look, or is it just to show where you want the colorbar? Since the color of the dots are not from the colorbar's colormap. I had a similar issue recently where I needed one colorbar for sets of points that used different colormap scales. Is that what you need too?

Comment: @FranciscaConcha-Ramírez thanks for your comment. The points were actually correct but not the colorbar. I have edited my post to make this clearer.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I think this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779462/2943652

Comment: I'm very sorry. It was in response to another question. I deleted it.

Comment: @FranciscaConcha-Ramírez looking at this again, I have noticed that the dots were shown as expected, but not really. I had messed up and showed the screenshot of the fixed code but had kept the comments in the edited code chunks in my question. My apologies, you were right in asking about that.

I have now edited my question as it should be. I kept the screenshots as they are qualitatively the same to what I get

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772083/1379826) I could edit my code to show the continuous colorbar.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 100), index=['S1','S2']).T
tars=np.random.choice([0,0.3,0.5,0.8,1], 100)
df=pd.concat([df,pd.Series(tars, name='group')],1)

cmap=matplotlib.cm.viridis
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,len(pd.unique(tars))))

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
targets=pd.unique(tars)
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    g=ax.scatter(
        df.loc[df.group==target, 'S1'], 
        df.loc[df.group==target, 'S2'],
        color=[color]
    )

norm = plt.Normalize(np.min(tars), np.max(tars))
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
ax.figure.colorbar(sm)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Good job on finding the answer to your question. You've made a mistake in `Normalize()` where you have used `min()` twice, instead of `min()` and `max()`, hence the wrong scale of the colorbar

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure to understand what you are trying to achieve with your for-loop.

Is this the output that you are looking for?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
g = ax.scatter(df['S1'],df['S2'],c=df['group'],cmap='viridis')
cbar = fig.colorbar(g)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Diziet, that is true, that is the output I'd like to see. For my purposes I believe I have to use the loop as other things are being plotted and added to the axes there depending on `colors` and `targets`. I must say my post had messed up the `cmap` in the loop, and it should've showed a line that was commented giving `color=[color]` instead of `cmap = cmap=matplotlib.cm.gnuplot2`.